# Buggy and Jittery overflow: scroll container if animating font-variation-settings inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I've got an unique problem.

I've noticed that if I have a `font-variation-setting` being animated even with simpler CSS animation it doesn’t allow my container to overflow nicely. Like it normally would with properties like `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch`

The gif below shows the shivering scroll container as I try to overdrag the container downwards.

Here is what I'm seeing on my ios 13.5.1 Safari browser (iOS Chrome too):

**Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/overflowing-variable-font-bug-isolation-1plxo**

Demo without React: https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/WNraJEV

[image]

Any tips for mitigating this issue? Are there related questions?

```
//html

<div className="App">
 <div className="overflow">
  <Weight />
 </div>
</div>

//css

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.App {
  font-family: "n", sans-serif;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: "touch";
  overflow-y: auto;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "n";
  src: url("variableFont.ttf");
}

//weight.js

const childAnimation = {
  start: {
    fontVariationSettings: `"wght" ${100}`,
    transition: { duration: 0.3, ease: linear }
  },
  end: { fontVariationSettings: `"wght" ${0}` }
};
```

Comment: There appears to be another layer of abstraction here than just JS, HTML, and CSS. Perhaps React? Note that it may be possible to use [Stack Snippets to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/338537/215552) that is runnable on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Hi, good shout. I did another simpler use case here without React: https://codepen.io/umbriel/pen/WNraJEV